# Adaptive Curve bevel thickness

Tags: bezier-curves

I would like the bevel thickness of a curve object to be 1 pixel wide, regardless of distance from camera. I say 1 pixel, but really I'm just looking for fine control. This feature, if it exists, might not be immune to denoising, because of the color data spike. Any ideas how to do this?